# javascript thumbnail gallery click to enlarge using addEventListener, remove/appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, appendchild, getelementsbytagname

I want to use addEventListener to thumbnail images, so that by clicking them one at a time, they show up in separate div as a large-size image (image sizing is css not relevant to my problem therefore not shown here). I can't pinpoint my problem here.

```js
var imgs = document.getElementById("thumbnails").getElementsByTagName("img");
var mainpic = document.getElementById("mainpic");
for (var x in imgs) {
 imgs[x].addEventListener('click', function(){
  mainpic.innerHTML = '';
  var dupenode = imgs[x].cloneNode();
  mainpic.appendChild(dupenode);
 }, false);
};
```

```html
<div id="thumbnails">
    <img src="im1.jpg" />
    <img src="im2.jpg" />
    <img src="im3.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="mainpic">
</div>
```

Comment: You need to replace `imgs[x].cloneNode();` with `this.cloneNode();`

Comment: Those images aren't keyboard accessible (you can't focus and click them with a keyboard). You're better off wrapping the `<img>`s in `<button>`s and adding the click event listener to the buttons. http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/keyboard-operation.html

Comment: did that, thanks for the suggestion. brought the imgs in the buttons along with cloneNode(true).